# Handling js intervals and cron jobs using pm2

Tags: node.js, pm2

I'm running a node app(with Express framework) using `pm2 start ./bin/www -i 8` which runs 8 instances of application, so far so good.
in one of my files i'm using interval to query database every minute.

```
setInterval(function () {
    // db query
}, 60000); // every minute
```

with this approach i'm querying database 8 times per minute(because of 8 instance of app is running) but i want to query 1 time per minute.

should i write a separete script for running intervals and cron jobs without pm2?

how to handle this?

Comment: Maybe this helps: `process.env.NODE_APP_INSTANCE === 0` http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/environment/#specific-environment-variables

Comment: @RolandStarke good idea! thanks

Comment: @RolandStarke post your comment as answer, i'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Ronald mentioned in comments above, we can check the main running app number using `process.env.NODE_APP_INSTANCE === 0`.

```
if (process.env.NODE_APP_INSTANCE === 0){
    // run cron jobs or etc here 
}
```